# Segmentation fault while running 'ng serve' in angular project

Tags: angular-cli, angular13

[Attached Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5AUz.png)

**System specifications**

```
> Angular CLI: 13.3.3 Node: 12.22.5 Package Manager: npm 8.7.0 OS: linux
> ia32 
   
Package                         Version
> @angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.3 
@angular-devkit/build-angular     13.3.3 
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.3
 @angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.3 
@angular/cli                    13.3.3
 @schematics/angular             13.3.3 
rxjs                            7.5.5 
typescript                      4.6.3
```

The project stops immediately after the ng serve build is deployed successfully.
The project was working fine until i added the bootstrap to my project
The angular.json file is as attached below.
[Attached image of angular.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYLnM.png)

Comment: Try adding ./ in front of the bootstrap path. Ex: ./node_modules/ .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"scripts": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

Worked flawlessly after updating the angular.json file  with the bootstrap script files path.